# React Native does not find a supported Android SDK version

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I´m trying to run react-native in a android emulator (ejected expo project), but react-native cannot find a proper version of the SDK. If I run **react-native doctor**, this is what the it is displayed:

[image]

Note that I've added every single possible Android SDK build version from Android Studio, and none of them seems to be accepted by react-native...

Any clues?